# Laravel - Getting [PDOException] could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I am using Lampp apache server and when I run the command `php artisan migrate` am getting this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = seo-cms and table_name = migrations)
[PDOException] could not find driver
```

I enabled the pdo extension from my `php.ini` from `/opt/lamp/etc/php.ini` and from `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`, I restarted the server, but it is not enough. Most likely I am missing something. Can you help me with this ?

Thx!

**[UPDATE]**
[image]

Comment: Why does it want the .dll when you use Linux?

Comment: @KoenHollander i do not understand your question, can you be more specific ?

Comment: Look, windows uses .dll files for a PHP driver. You error messages reffers to a .dll file. But linus must us a .so file for the extension.

Comment: I just updated my post with the result of phpinfo();

Comment: by executing this: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` . It fix my problem. Thx

Comment: @Chester Great Dear.Solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I executed this: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` and it fixed my problem. But I recommend you to give up on `lampp` and use the `apache service2`. It is more complicated to install and set configurations on `lampp`